# Editing fields in a table from php

Tags: php, mysql

Good afternoon, I hope you can help me, I need to update the values ​​of an entire column, I have a column called "img" in which I have:

```
../img/user/000001.jpg
```

I would like to modify it so that only left:

```
000001.jpg
```

users to update I occupy this code:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
mysql_query("UPDATE images SET user = 'new_user' WHERE user = 'user'");
mysql_close($conexion);
?>
```

but now I feel the need to update the path to the images, but they are more than 5000 and I want to do with php to save time.

I just need to remove the first 12 characters of the "img" column, as I can do this with php?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: They _all_ start with exactly `../img/user/`? You can easily call `REPLACE(img, '../img/user/', '')` to replace the string with an empty string in an `UPDATE` statement

Comment: By the way, doing it in PHP isn't a time saver here :) If you want to do one-time operations on your database, it is better to do so with a MySQL client than to write PHP code around it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski the more than 5000 fields begin with the same string "../img/user/" Might help me with the final code just to save a php and run it from the browser in the same way I do to update the names user? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't necessary for this, it can be done in pure SQL

```
UPDATE images SET img = SUBSTRING(img, 13, LENGTH(img) - 12)
WHERE SUBSTRING(img, 1, 12) = '../img/user/'
```

Comment: Error
consulta SQL:

UPDATE images SET img = SUBSTRING(img, 12, LEN(img))
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1305 - FUNCTION db_i.LEN does not exist

Comment: What I need is to delete the first 12 characters, but the name of the image is like this, otherwise it will not work the code of index.php, greetings.

Comment: @altoca This query will delete the first 12 characters **if** the first 12 characters are "../img/user/". It would be possible to blindly just delete the first 12, but this way is safer.

Comment: No longer gives me error, but says "0" rows affected, not changing anything, see if I'm doing well: I go to phpmyadmin, I select the database, then the images table, the top selected SQL, hit the code that give me and run to continue and nothing happens. Any idea? where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @altoca Are you sure the first twelve characters are exactly `../img/user/`? Never uppercase, no space in front, etc? If you want, you could try just blindly deleting the first 12 characters with `UPDATE images SET img = SUBSTRING(img, 13, LENGTH(img) - 12)` but make sure you back up your table or database before you do.